# Drupal CMS help, how to allow visitors to make account/profile on my website?

Tags: drupal-7, content-management-system

I was researching different CMS's and I found that Drupal is used a lot and I thought it would be the best CMS. However, I'm very new to CMS's and how they function so I don't think I understand how it's working. The admin dashboard is stored under "url/drupal-test" so whenever I go to that page, I log in as admin and everything. Does anyone know any documentation on using Drupal to allow users to make a profile for my site? I figured Drupal would give me a "mysite/drupal-test/userlogin" page or something along those lines. If I'm not being clear, please tell me to clarify in a certain area. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this would be the best guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-users) for you to learn Drupal user management system.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that guide out, I really appreciate the source.

Answer (score 0):

the user login page is usually here:

```
/user
```

administering users in Drupal 7 is here:

```
/admin/people
```

you can adjust the settings, such as whether other users can create accounts here:

```
/admin/config/people/accounts
```

At this last link you can specify whether only administrators can create accounts, or any vistor, or any vistor with administrator approval.